# Xamarin display notification in notification bar once the file is downloaded

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this code for downloading a file which runs correct:

```
var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(item.FileDataAsBase64String);
                var downloadDirectory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(downloadDirectory, "test.pdf");

                var streamWriter = File.Create(filePath);
                streamWriter.Close();
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, base64EncodedBytes);
```

I'm able to locate the file I downloaded in the Downloads folder, but also I want to show a notification in the notification bar that the file has been downloaded and with a click in the notifications the user to be able to open the downloaded file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Plugin.LocalNotification](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification) to show the notification once the file is downloaded.

```
try
{
    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(item.FileDataAsBase64String);
    var downloadDirectory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
    var filePath = Path.Combine(downloadDirectory, "test.pdf");

    var streamWriter = File.Create(filePath);
    streamWriter.Close();
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, base64EncodedBytes);

    DisplayNotification("test.pdf downloaded successfully", filePath);
}
catch(System.Exception e)  
{  
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
    DisplayNotification("Download Failed",string.Empty);
} 


public void DisplayNotification(string message, string filePath)
{
    var notification = new NotificationRequest
    {
        NotificationId = 100,
        Title = "Your App name",
        Description = message,
        ReturningData = filePath, // Returning data when tapped on notification.
        NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30) // Used for Scheduling local notification, if not specified notification will show immediately.
    };
    NotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
}
```

**Note:** Make sure to initialize the plugin setup in both the project iOS and Android.

Comment: Thanks @Himanshu how can I point to the file which got downloaded in the notification so when the notification is clicked the file will be opened?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the filePath inside OnLocalNotificationTapped event and make use of Xamarin.forms pdf viewer, pass the filepath to the pdf viewer it will open the pdf

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try now

Comment: Update your Xamarin.Android.Support.Compact library also android target framework should be 9.0+

Comment: I did, that's all good now, marking your answer as correct. Now can you please help me with the pdf viewer, how can I open the file directly in the native pdf viewer as soon as its downloaded? I just asked that here at SO thanks